# Xamarin forms getting error The type or namespace name 'XamlFilePathAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml'

Tags: xamarin.forms

getting this error while adding a new Forms xaml page in visual studio for creating xamrin forms cross platform app .As I am new to xamarin plz help

the Error is as follows

The type or namespace name 'XamlFilePathAttributeAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   App1.Droid

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out i just updated my nugetpackes and restated the Visual studio and it fixed it.